# Passing objects created in ArrayList to another method of another class

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have a class named AirMain where I took in inputs from the user of airline information. I have another class named Airline where constructors are created to store the user input as as Airline object which then store into ArrayList named "info".

I have another ArrayList named "query" storing objects from Airline class but different parameter from the "info" ArrayList.

When I tried to pass both of these ArrayList to another class method (named earliestDepart() in Airline class), I receive error "Cannot find symbol; location: class Object". It is quite a lengthy code, so please see below for a snapshot of the passing to other method of another class and the point where error happens.

Please advise me how do I pass Arraylist containing of objects to another class for process. Thanks in advance!

**Code in AirMain Class**

```
ArrayList <Airline> info = new ArrayList<Airline>();
ArrayList <Airline> query = new ArrayList<Airline>();
Airline createAirline = new Airline (fromCity, toCity, departTime, arriveTime, cost);
info.add(createAirline);
Airline createQuery = new Airline(type, fromCity, toCity);
query.add(createQuery);
if (query.get(i).getType() == 1) { query.get(i).earliestDepart(info);  }//end of if type 1
```

**Code in Airline Class**

```
public void earliestDepart(ArrayList info){
String retrieve = info.get(i).getFromCity();//error kicks into this statement 
}
```

Comment: What is `i`?  I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: The "i" is define in the "for" loop.
for (int i=0; i<numOp; i++){
//codes
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the info argument in your `earliestDepart()` method like this:

```
public void earliestDepart(List<Airline> info){
String retrieve = info.get(i).getFromCity();//error kicks into this statement 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Pass by value to `earliestDepart` method.*

```
public void earliestDepart(List<Airline> infoList){...}
```